# Continuous RTSP stream recording with ffmpeg. Can I optimize it to not damage the SD card?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, armbian

I have got an IP camera with RTSP stream. I decided to record the stream using ffmpeg (version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1) on the Odroid-N2 device with Armbian. I have created a .sh script which is launched by Croon every minute. It checks if the ffmpeg recording is active for selected camera and also deletes files older than 7 days:

```
#!/bin/bash
RecordPathAndFind='/home/mona/CameraRecordings/Camera1/'
SegmentTime=900
MinutesAfterDeleteOldFiles=10080
DaysSecurityLimit=31

tempoutput=$(ps aux | grep ffmpeg | grep $RecordPathAndFind)
if [ ${#tempoutput} -ge 5 ];
then
      echo "FFMPEG with record command is already running. Skipping.\n"
else
      echo "FFMPEG with record command is not running. Starting now...\n"
      FFMPEGSTART=$(su - mona -c "cd /home/mona; /usr/bin/screen -dmS ffmpegcamera1 ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i 'rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.xxx:554/onvif1' -vcodec copy -c:a aac -map 0 -f segment -segment_time $(echo $SegmentTime) -segment_format mp4 -strftime 1 $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4")
fi

currenthourminutes=$(date +%M)
if [ "$currenthourminutes" == "00" ]; then
    echo "Current Minute is 00. Checking for old files to delete.\n"
    FILESDELETECOMMAND=$(find $(echo $RecordPathAndFind) -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +$(echo $MinutesAfterDeleteOldFiles) -mtime -$(echo $DaysSecurityLimit) -name '*.mp4' -ls -exec rm {} \;)
else
    echo "Current Minute is NOT 00. Skipping.\n"
fi
```

The script works fine, but I'm afraid of the life of the SD card in this device. I detected that ffmpeg is continuously writing the mp4 file (file size grows all the time). I think it would be better if ffmpeg waited for ~1MiB before flushing it to disk.

I tried different ffmpeg settings (adding "blocksize", "flush_packets", "reorder_queue_size" and few others I can't recall now), unfortunately it didn't change anything. The mp4 file size was increasing all the time (even by few KBs).

The first question is: Should I be worried about the microSD card life when ffmpeg is all the time writing the file (current environment)?

The second question is: Are there any other ffmpeg optimization settings which I missed?

If my fears regarding the SD card life are correct, can you please recommend some other things which I could add to my script (or change in system) in order to increase the life of micro SD cards (or USB sticks) used for recording purposes? I was thinking about using the ramdisk, and then manually move the files, however this could cause files loss in case of system reboot, hang, or power outage.

EDIT:
Here is the command I use to check file size changes:

```
root@odroidn2:/home/mona/CameraRecordings/Camera1# printf "`date +"%m-%d-%y_%H:%S:%N"` `echo "Bytes:"` `stat --printf "%s\n" 2019-07-10_18-01-00.mp4`\n"
07-10-19_18:28:616623697 Bytes: 28443805
07-10-19_18:29:497492966 Bytes: 28453943
07-10-19_18:29:811378969 Bytes: 28458099
07-10-19_18:30:162532642 Bytes: 28724960
07-10-19_18:30:513455929 Bytes: 28730146
07-10-19_18:30:832042221 Bytes: 28734694
07-10-19_18:31:204934593 Bytes: 28739202
07-10-19_18:31:587997659 Bytes: 28744450
07-10-19_18:32:056139192 Bytes: 28750415
07-10-19_18:32:490959812 Bytes: 28755253
07-10-19_18:32:836352316 Bytes: 28757934
07-10-19_18:33:209513158 Bytes: 28762371
07-10-19_18:33:595689070 Bytes: 29021552
07-10-19_18:33:970968755 Bytes: 29026202
07-10-19_18:34:412742761 Bytes: 29031995
07-10-19_18:34:825309867 Bytes: 29037579
07-10-19_18:35:219852935 Bytes: 29043515
07-10-19_18:35:598878409 Bytes: 29046993
07-10-19_18:35:994067048 Bytes: 29051547
07-10-19_18:36:383952621 Bytes: 29055235
07-10-19_18:36:822644535 Bytes: 29331875
07-10-19_18:37:233137175 Bytes: 29336695
07-10-19_18:37:617277956 Bytes: 29343653
07-10-19_18:38:022776087 Bytes: 29348487
07-10-19_18:38:630347795 Bytes: 29357002
07-10-19_18:39:304204108 Bytes: 29364381
```

As I can see the file size increased by 10138 bytes (10 kilobytes) within 1 second.

Comment: ffmpeg should not be writing every few KB - it should be every 256 kB except when writing the header at the start and the closing writes at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the question and added the file size changes log. Seems like it increased by 10 KB within 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using a self-written script, executed by the croon:

```
* * * * * /home/mona/mona_ffmpeg_camera1_record.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
RecordPathAndFind='/home/mona/CameraRecordings/Tmps_Camera1/'
RecordPathCopyTo='/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-XXX/Camera1_Recordings/'
#900 = 15 mins
SegmentTime=900
#7 days = 10080
MinutesAfterDeleteOldFiles=10080
DaysSecurityLimit=31
DeleteOldFiles=false
MakeRamDisk=true
CopyFilesToHDD=true

tempoutput=$(ps aux | grep ffmpeg | grep $RecordPathAndFind)
if [ ${#tempoutput} -ge 5 ];
then
      echo "FFMPEG with record command is already running. Skipping.\n"
      #Check if ffmpeg didn't hang:
      PIDOfFFmpeg=$(ps aux | grep ffmpeg | grep $RecordPathAndFind | grep -v 'SCREEN' | awk '{print $2}')
      echo "Found existing ffmpeg PID: $PIDOfFFmpeg.\n"
      #ModificationTime=$(stat -L -c %Y /proc/$PIDOfFFmpeg/fd/4);
      ModificationTime=$(stat -L -c %Y /proc/$PIDOfFFmpeg/fd/2);
      echo "Last File modification time: $ModificationTime.\n"
      if [ $ModificationTime -le $(($EPOCHSECONDS - 60)) ];
      then
        echo "Very old modification time. Restarting ffmpeg at next run.\n"
        kill $PIDOfFFmpeg
        #Backup existing files:
        FILES_TO_COPY=$(ls -lt "$RecordPathAndFind" | awk '{ print $9 }' | tail -n +2)
        FILES_COUNT=0
        for f in $FILES_TO_COPY; do
          echo "Currently processing file: $f"
          FILES_COUNT=$FILES_COUNT+1
          if [[ $FILES_COUNT -gt 0 ]]; then
             echo "File not skipped, copying..."
             cp "$RecordPathAndFind$f" "$RecordPathCopyTo"
             echo "Removing file..."
             rm "$RecordPathAndFind$f"
          fi
        done
      fi
    
      #test `stat -L -c %Y /proc/$PIDOfFFmpeg/fd/4` -ge $(($EPOCHSECONDS - 60)) || kill $PIDOfFFmpeg
else
      if [ "$MakeRamDisk" = true ] ; then
      echo "Mounting Ramdisk...\n"
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      umount -A $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)
      fi
      
      if ping -c 1 192.168.1.111 &> /dev/null
      then
      echo "FFMPEG with record command is not running. Starting now...\n"
      FFMPEGSTART=$(su - mona -c "cd /home/mona; /usr/bin/screen -dmS ffmpegcamera1 ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i 'rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.111:554/onvif1' -vcodec copy -c:a aac -map 0 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -f segment -segment_time $(echo $SegmentTime) -segment_format mp4 -strftime 1 $(echo $RecordPathAndFind)%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4")
      #echo $FFMPEGSTART
      else
      echo "ERROR. Pinging 192.168.1.111 failed. Will retry in 1 minute...\n"
      fi
fi

currenthourminutes=$(date +%M)
if [ "$DeleteOldFiles" = true ] ; then
if [ "$currenthourminutes" == "00" ]; then
    echo "Current Minute is 00. Checking for old files to delete.\n"
    FILESDELETECOMMAND=$(find $(echo $RecordPathAndFind) -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +$(echo $MinutesAfterDeleteOldFiles) -mtime -$(echo $DaysSecurityLimit) -name '*.mp4' -ls -exec rm {} \;)
else
    echo "Current Minute is NOT 00. Skipping.\n"
fi
fi

if [ "$CopyFilesToHDD" = true ] ; then

SIZE=$(du -s -B1 "$RecordPathAndFind" | cut -f1)
echo "Folder size is: $SIZE"
#900MiB
COPY_WHEN_SIZE_BYTES=943718400
#COPY_WHEN_SIZE_BYTES=401219456

if [[ $SIZE -gt $COPY_WHEN_SIZE_BYTES ]]; then
echo 'Folder Size is greater than: '$COPY_WHEN_SIZE_BYTES' bytes. Copying...'
FILES_TO_COPY=$(ls -lt "$RecordPathAndFind" | awk '{ print $9 }' | tail -n +2)
FILES_COUNT=0
for f in $FILES_TO_COPY; do
  echo "Currently processing file: $f"
  FILES_COUNT=$FILES_COUNT+1
  if [[ $FILES_COUNT -gt 1 ]]; then
     echo "File not skipped, copying..."
     cp "$RecordPathAndFind$f" "$RecordPathCopyTo"
     echo "Removing file..."
     rm "$RecordPathAndFind$f"
  fi
done
fi

fi
```

It works in the following way:

- The script detects if another instance is already running (this should be improved but is enough for me now).
- It records 15 minutes parts to the ram disk (I set around 1GB, because my device has 4GB RAM).
- When the ram disk is nearly full, it copies files from it to an old 2.5'' HDD (connected by USB), with power saving enabled, so it spins only for a few seconds, every few hours.
- This might cause data loss in the ram disk, in case of electricity outage, but I prefer this method because it's very quiet and the spinning disk doesn't annoy me at nights :)

I've been using this method for around 2 years now, and I'm happy because I didn't damage any SD card.